# Unable to Display Media Player for Live TV in React Native using react-native-video

Tags: android, react-native, live-streaming

> I'm working on a React Native app that aims to display live TV
> channels using the react-native-video package. I've followed the
> documentation and implemented the necessary code, but I'm encountering
> an issue where the media player is not being displayed when selecting
> a channel.

I have already ensured the following:

The react-native-video package is installed and linked correctly.
The stream URLs (streamUrl) are valid and accessible.
The permissions for internet access are included in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
However, the video component is not displaying as expected, and I'm not seeing any error messages in the console.

If anyone has experience with integrating the react-native-video component for streaming live TV or any suggestions on what might be causing this issue, your assistance would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

interface Channel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  streamUrl: string;
}

const channels: Channel[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Channel 1',
    streamUrl: 'https://daddylivehd.one/embed/stream-51.php',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Channel 2',
    streamUrl: 'https://daddylivehd.one/embed/stream-32.php',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Channel 3',
    streamUrl: 'https://daddylivehd.one/embed/stream-116.php',
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [selectedChannel, setSelectedChannel] = useState<Channel | null>(null);

  const handleChannelPress = (channel: Channel) => {
    setSelectedChannel(channel);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 20,
          color: 'red',
          textAlign: 'center',
          marginTop: 20,
        }}>
        {'Live TV Channels'}
      </Text>

      <FlatList
        data={channels}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleChannelPress(item)}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'blue', marginTop: 10}}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />

      {selectedChannel && (
        <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, textAlign: 'center'}}>
            {`Currently watching: ${selectedChannel.name}`}
          </Text>
          <Video
            source={{uri: selectedChannel.streamUrl}}
            style={{flex: 1}}
            resizeMode="cover"
            controls
            onError={error => console.log('Video error: ', error)}
          />
          <Button
            title="Stop Watching"
            onPress={() => setSelectedChannel(null)}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Output Image of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4zZo.png)